# Activate most recently active window in a group with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am making an autohotkey script to switch to a text editor, but depending on what I'm working on I may have different text editors.

I created a group TextEditor with my three text editors:

```
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_class Notepad++
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_exe Code.exe
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_class Notepad
```

The group seems to be created properly but whenever I use `GroupActivate, TextEditor, R` it always opens Nodepad++ and repeated presses switch between the three editors.

I want it to open whatever I last used first, like if I was using Code and switched to another program it should activate Code again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_class Notepad++
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_exe Code.exe
GroupAdd, TextEditor, ahk_class Notepad

F1::
IfWinActive ahk_group TextEditor
    GroupActivate, TextEditor, R
else
{
    list := ""
    ; windows are retrieved in order from the most recent to the last activated:
    WinGet, myWindows, List, ahk_group TextEditor
    WinActivate, ahk_id %myWindows1% ; activate the most recently active window in this group
}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#List

Comment: This works great. I was already using WinGet, id, list before to bring all windows in a certain class to front, just didn't think of using it for getting the topmost window

Comment: Works great.

Too bad there's no `IDFirst` SubCommand, while there's an [IDLast](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinGet.htm#IDLast)

I'd get rid of the loop and activate the first window with `%id1%` directly. I proposed an edit.

Comment: Note that AHK 2's `GroupActivate` has this behavior by default, so no need for `IfWinActive` and `WinGet` any more.